# $f(z)$ entire and $|f(z)| \le (1+|z|)^n$ implies $f(z)$ is polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, proof-explanation, entire-functions

Suppose that $f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}$ is an entire function, $n\ge 1$ is an integer, and that $|f(z)|\le (1+|z|)^n$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$. Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

*Proof*:

Since $f$ is entire, we can write it as $$f(z) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty c_m z^m$$

By Cauchy Estimates, for any closed disk $\mathbb{D}$ of radius $r>0$ centred about $z=0$, $$|f^{(m)}(0)|\le \frac{M_r m!}{r^m}$$ where $M_r=\sup\{|f(z)|:z\in\mathbb{D}\}\le (1+r)^n$. Let $n<m$, then

$$ |c_m|=\frac{|f^{(m)(0)}|}{m!}\le \frac{M_r m!}{m! r^m}=\frac{M_r}{r^m}\le \frac{(1+r)^n}{r^m} $$

Also, $|c_m|=\lim\limits_{r\to \infty}|c_m|\le 0$.

> Hence, $f(z)=c_0+c_1z+\dots+c_nz^n$ is a polynomial of at most degree $m$.

*My question is this*: how does the above proof show that $f$ is a polynomial?

Comment: The power series terminates of the entire function terminates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Cauchy's Integral Formula, for an analytic function $f$ we have

$$f^{(m)}(0)=\frac{m!}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=r>0}\frac{f(z)}{z^{m+1}}\,dz$$

Given that $|f(z)|\le (1+|z|)^n$, we have the estimate for $f^{(m)}(z_0)$

$$|f^{(m)}(0)|\le \frac{m!}{2\pi }\frac{2\pi r (1+r^n)}{r^{m+1}}$$

For $m>n$, we find that

$$f^{(m)}(0)=0$$

Thus, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{f^{m}(0)}{m!}z^m\\\\
&=\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{f^{m}(0)}{m!}z^m+\underbrace{\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty\frac{f^{m}(0)}{m!}z^m}_{=0}\\\\
&=\underbrace{\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{f^{m}(0)}{m!}z^m}_{\text{A polynomial of order}\,n}
\end{align}$$

Hence, $f$ is a polynomial of, at most, order $n$.

Comment: Right, it's at most of order $n$, not $m$ like it was in the proof.

Comment: @sequence Yes, $n$ is a fixed number such that $|f(z)|\le (1+|z|)^n$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.  So, stepping back, this result tells us that if an entire function is bounded by a function that is $O(z^n)$ as $z\to \infty$, then it is a polynomial of, at most, order $n$.