# Is there an entire function satisfying $|f(z)|=|z|+1$ for every $|z|\geq2017$?

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

Is there a holomorphic function $f \in Hol(\Bbb C)$ such that $|f(z)|=|z|+1$ for every $|z|\geq2017$ ?

I tried defining $g(z)=\frac{1}{f(z)}$. Such $g$ is clearly holomorphic and bounded for $|z| \geq 2017$. I want to show that $g$ is holomorphic in $|z| \leq 2017$ and then conclude that $g$ is constant. For that I want to show that $f$ has no zeros in $|z| \leq 2017$. I tried to prove it by Rouche theorem, but didn't succeed. Any ideas?

Edit: the post similar to mine doesn't solve my problem, because the ending of the proof is not clear. Where is the contradiction?

Comment: $h(z)=f(1/z)$ is far from being surjective around $z=0$, therefore it has a pole and not an essential singularity.

Comment: @MartinR I read the answer in this post, It is helpful but I'm not sure I understand the end. Why does $f(z)= C$ and not another constant? and how can one finish the proof?

Comment: Knowingly posting a duplicate. Why?

Comment: @Did Not knowingly, I read it after Marting R posted this comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer.** An [entire function has a Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)
$$f(z)=a_0+\sum\limits_{n=1}a_nz^n \tag{1}$$
[where](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem) 
$$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$$
As a result
$$|a_n|=\left|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=r}\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz\right|\leq
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{|z|=r} \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\right||dz|= \\
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{|z|=r} \frac{|z|+1}{|z|^{n+1}}|dz|=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{|z|=r} \frac{r+1}{r^{n+1}}|dz|=\\
\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{r+1}{r^{n+1}}\cdot 2\pi r=
\frac{r+1}{r^{n}}$$
Taking the limit $\lim\limits_{r\rightarrow\infty}$, we have that $|a_n|=0$ for all $n\geq2$, thus from $(1)$
$$f(z)=a_0+a_1z, |a_1|\leq 1 \tag{2}$$

Going further, it's easy to show that $|a_1|=1$ from 
$$|f(x)|=|a_0+a_1z|=|z|+1 \Rightarrow \left|\frac{a_0}{z}+a_1\right| = 1 + \frac{1}{|z|}$$
and taking $\lim\limits_{z\rightarrow\infty}$.

Can you continue with this?

Comment: This is also the argument given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2220337/fz-entire-and-fz-le-1zn-implies-fz-is-polynomial

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand that $f$ must be of this form. I'm still having trouble getting to contradiction...

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It is almost an algorithm, you can easily tell I copy/pasted it from here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2632621/let-f-be-an-entire-function-if-100-log-mid-z-mid-geq-mid-fz-mid-fo/2632660#2632660, which is also my answer. Feel free to vote for this question to be flagged as a duplicate. I already did.

Comment: @user401516 I added more details.

Comment: @rtybase I was not arguing about who came first or what, just connecting related things together.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer (continuation of rtybase's answer where we got to $f(z)=a_0+a_1z$).**

Consider the circle $|z|=C$ where $C$ is a constant greater than $2017$. When $z$ runs over this circle, $a_1z$ runs over the circle centered at the origin with radius $|a_1|C$.

Thus $f(z)$ runs over the circle centered at $a_0$ with radius $|a_1|C$.

Your condition that $|f(z)|=C+1$ implies then that $a_0=0$ (the centre of the circle where $f(z)$ lives), and more importantly that $|a_1|C=C+1$ for all $C>2017$. This last condition is impossible since $\frac{C+1}{C}$ is not a constant.

Comment: Why does $|f(z)|=C+1$ implies $a_0=0, |a1|C=C+1$?

Comment: Because $|f(z)|$ being constant implies that $f(z)$ lives on a circle centered at the origin.